# Tracking down owner of a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In our app we're about to (finally..) switch from raw pointers to using C++11 `smart_ptr` templates.

We do have the occasional bug in our app with (non C++) objects still keeping references to our C++ objects causing crashes in the past when accessing the then-dealloc'd objects.

Not sure if this is a silly question - but is there a way to take advantage of the `smart_ptr` objects and '*dump*' the objects still holding on to the C++ objects when none are expected to hold a reference to one any more?

I guess what I'm asking for is **a way to list all owners of `smart_ptr<MyClass>`** at a certain point in time.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: `smart_ptr<>` doesn't keep owners' list, it keeps owners' count. That said, you can add owners' list to the implementation in no time (in debug).

Comment: How are you planning to incorporate non-C++ code in your smart pointer scheme?

Comment: @n.m. This is a Cocoa app with high-level code is written in Obj-C++. Low-level business logic is platform independent and C++ and ignorant of the higher-level, non-C++ code. Having said that technically speaking Obj-C++ **is** C++ (or a superset), though just holding references to the C++ objects

Comment: Use shared_ptr/weak_ptr in your non-C++ Code.

Comment: Not sure how much Valgrind would help with `shared_ptr` specifically, but have you tried it ?

Comment: By `dump` do you mean like telling them to no longer hold the reference to the smart pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Without creating your own smart pointer classes that wrap `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` (ignore the deprecated `std::auto_ptr`) that tracks this information, there is no way to do that.
The standard classes themself do not track this information (would be too costly).

Another alternative would be to modify the code of your standard library implementation to track that info. Less invasive on *your* code since you can keep using the standard names. But probably a bit more tricky than just wrapping the classes and use the wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

> We do have the occasional bug in our app with (non C++) objects still keeping references to our C++ objects causing crashes in the past when accessing the then-dealloc'd objects.

This is serious and must not be ignored.

If you're giving 3rd party library components observer status on your objects, then it stands to reason that the 3rd party component's observer must not outlive your object.

There are 3 common causes for this problem:

1. Improper lifetime management of the 3rd-party component (you're deleting the observed object before shutting down the 3rd party observer)
2. improperly detected crossing cases (resulting in 1, above)
3. In the case were you are the component, you must take orders on from the 3rd party framework as to when you may dispose of your object.

Before involving `shared_ptr`s you ought to first prove that the shared_ptr may legitimately destroy the object. If the 3rd party component has a 'deregister' method, then you can solve this by:

1. Ensure ownership of the 3rd party component and your observed object are controlled by the same shared_ptr, or
2. Use a custom deleter on the shared_ptr to cause de-registration on your controlled object on the 3rd party object before finally deleting it.

If none of this is clear, it's time to take a good long look at your object lifetimes. It often helps to draw sequence diagrams.

Comment: The situation is a bit more complex: Our app is a complex UI app with dozens of views/view-controllers, most of which keep references to the low-level C++ objects. Some bugs (which of course do exist in any non-trivial app) cause some of the view-controllers (or potentially just parts of them - check out blocks in OS X programming) to stick around.
The idea is to basically track down the bugs in the higher levels of the app by gathering more details via smart_ptrs

Comment: @atv sif you have a complex hand-crafted ui layer that is holding onto internal state pointers from your core, consider a different design.  Often I find it useful to try to approach the ideal of "ui is in different process than core", with as much communication as possible in simple near-serialized interfaces.  (Actually going all the way to a separate process may not be required, as is actually serializing: but flat data instead of state pointers, ids jnstead of pointers, etc).  Ui is messy, giving it access to core engine guts is recipie for infinite bugs.

Comment: @ATV objective-c (and swift) blocks are horrid because they cause circular references almost by default (as you have found). If I were you (and I have done this before) I would rename all the .m files to .mm and drop in a c++ lifetime tracker into each block. Then carefully re-engineer each block so that it only references a __weak copy of self rather than self (referencing self in a callback block is a 100% chance of a resource leak). I built myself a objective-c++ version of weak_ptr/shared_ptr for NSObject-derived types because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't believe this is possible for any out of the box c++ smart pointers. You can trivially wrap a shared_ptr to achieve the same effect though.

```
template<typename T>
class mySmartPtr : boost::noncopyable{
    public:
         // This method should be the only way this object can be copied
         // as the copy constructors are made private
         // The newOwnerName parameter can be used to populate m_onwers.
         static mySmartPtr<T> newOwner(mySmartPtr<T>&, std::string newOnwerName); 
    private:
         std::shared_ptr<T> m_ptr;
         static std::vector<std::string> m_owners;
};
```

Comment: "`boost::noncopyable`" - Why? Just declare the copy and move operators as `=delete` if you don't want the class to be copyable. No need to involve boost.

Comment: sure. `=delete` also works, but is not supported by all the compilers just yet. The objective was to stop copying of that object and there are multiple ways to achieve it. How to do it was not central to what I was saying.

Comment: @cplusplusrat : Code for the standard specified in the question (C++14 in this case), or the current version of the standard if not specified (C++14 presently).

Comment: :), like I said, how to make copy constructors private is not central to my solution at all. If the `boost::noncopyable` makes you uncomfortable, use `delete`.